# Grunt+Foundation: css/foundation.css created, content [object Object]

Tags: gruntjs, zurb-foundation, grunt-contrib-watch

I just got started with Bolt.cm (CMS) which comes along with Foundation for frontend.

I've installed Node, NPM, Node-sass, Bower and Grund and started a "grunt watch" in the theme directory.

Grunt is running ("waiting") and when I edit a file in the scss folder (the one from the theme of course, not from the bower_components, I know I should not edit them) the task is successfully executed:

> Running "sass:dist" (sass) task.
>
> File "css/foundation.css" created.
>
> Done, without errors.

Theme & versions:

- I copied this theme to modify it locally: https://github.com/bolt/base-2014
- Grunt version is grunt-cli v0.1.13
- NPM version 1.3.10
- bower version 1.4.1

**The problem**

When i open css/foundation.css, the file does not contain CSS code, but only `[object Object]` as text.

This is the output when i run `grunt --verbose`:

```
grunt --verbose
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK

Registering "grunt-sass" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /var/www/bolt/theme/avoe/node_modules/grunt-sass/package.json...OK
Parsing /var/www/bolt/theme/avoe/node_modules/grunt-sass/package.json...OK
Loading "sass.js" tasks...OK
+ sass

Registering "grunt-contrib-watch" local Npm module tasks.
Reading /var/www/bolt/theme/avoe/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Parsing /var/www/bolt/theme/avoe/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/package.json...OK
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ build, default

No tasks specified, running default tasks.
Running tasks: default

Running "default" task

Running "build" task

Running "sass" task

Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Verifying property sass.dist exists in config...OK
Files: scss/foundation.scss -> css/foundation.css
Options: includePaths=["bower_components/foundation/scss"], outputStyle="compressed", sourceComments="none"
Writing css/foundation.css...OK
File "css/foundation.css" created.
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue by going into node_modules folder, removing and reinstalling grunt-sass and node-sass:

`rm -rf node-sass
rm -rf grunt-sass
npm install node-sass
npm install grunt-sass`

The reinstallation of grunt sass updated my foundation-libsass-template repo, which is where i think the issue may have lay.

It may be that you don't even need to touch node-sass, so perhaps give grunt-sass a go first.

Hope this helps.